# How to test async actions that returns promise?

Tags: jestjs

```
fetchMock.get(`http://localhost:8080/data/v1/shopping-cart.json#/`).then(res => {
            console.log('response  ', res);
 });
```

I am passing `http://localhost:8080/data/v1/shopping-cart.json#/` as a base URL to the fetchMock.get() method and getting the following output:

> fetch-mock: Invalid parameters passed to fetch-mock

What could be a reason?

Answer (score 1):

First, you actually misuse `fetchMock()`. Check [their docs](http://www.wheresrhys.co.uk/fetch-mock/#api-mockingmock) on details. It's expected you to pass url and callback as part of `.get()`:

```
fetchMock.get('http://localhost:8080/data/v1/shopping-cart.json', (url, opts) => {
  return {body: 'aaa', status: 200}
});
fetch('http://localhost:8080/data/v1/shopping-cart.json').then(res => console.log(res));
```

Second you should not use hash part(`#/` in your case) for URL mocked. Browser does not send this part to server so I believe your mock may not work at all(until `fetch-mock` strips this part for mocks under the hood, but I'd not rely on that).

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the fetch method to return mock promise, as below:

in your test case:

```
window.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 

   new Promise((resolve) => 
     resolve({ /** dummy response object here */ })
  )
);
```

and then when you call the action with async calls, the result should be equal to what you were doing in the `then` handler (success handler)

similarly, you can `reject` the promise to test the `catch` handler.
Hope it helps.